# How to convert a string to its unicode escapes?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a `char` array to unicode-escaped`char` array.

Say I have a string "**C:/İmüp**".
How can I convert it to **C:/\u0130m\u00fcp** as `char` array or `const char`?

(I get "C:/Hello İmüp" as char array via ExpandEnvironmentStrings(), then i need to write that to a file with its unicode escapes)

I tried typecast converting, `std::stringstream` and ASCII tables, looked up for examples on C++ json encoders, however i couldn't get it working

Comment: How do you determine which characters to keep? Would `"\u0043\u003a\u002f\u0130\u006d\u00fc\u0070"` be acceptable too?

Comment: @hvd characters above 127 will be escaped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::wstring env;
// fill env with data from ExpandEnvironmentStringsW()...

std::stringstream ss;
for (std::wstring::iterator iter = env.begin(); iter != env.end(); ++iter)
{
    if (*iter <= 127)
        ss << (char) *iter;
    else
        ss << "\\u" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << (int)*iter;
}

std::string str = ss.str();
// use str as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for. However is there any chance that i can do it without wstring? I mean, if i use this i need to convert `char array` to `wstring`

Comment: If you use `ExpandEnvironmentStringsW()` directly, like it has been suggested to you, then you will not have a `char` array to begin with, you will have a `wchar_t` array instead. You could then loop through that array directly, you don't have to use `wstring`. That just made the `for` loop easier to write. The important thing is to look at each `wchar_t` and decide how to format it based on its value. Since you are dealing with non-ASCII characters, you should not be using `ExpandEnvironmentStringsA()` to begin with, you would have to convert to `wchar_t` anyway to get proper results.

Comment: Now i got it, thank you again. I was spent my 2+ days to achieve that :)

Answer (score 2):

First convert it from char array to wchar_t array, using the system-default code page.

Then write trivial code that walks over your wchar_t array and escapes every Unicode character with code >= 128.

P.S. Better yet, make your application Unicode so it will use Unicode version of ExpandEnvironmentStrings. This way you will only have to escape the string, plus your app will still work correctly if some environmental string contains a character that doesn’t fit in `char` with your system-default code page.

Comment: There are various characters below 128 that could need escaping too.

Comment: It depends on why does he need the escaping. For example in standard RTF format, only characters with code >= 128 are required to be escaped.

Comment: You do not need to make the app Unicode (but you should) in order to use the Unicode version of `ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`, you can just call `ExpandEnvironmentStringsW()` directly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
string yourAsciiString = "this is test";
string yourUnicodeString = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(yourAsciiString));
```